# Breakpoint not getting hit inside Kotlin callback in Intellij

Tags: intellij-idea, kotlin, breakpoints

In the code below I put a breakpoint on the line where it says `println("yoyo")`, but it's not getting hit. This is on IntelliJ IDEA 2016.2.5
Build #IC-162.2228.15, built on October 14, 2016. How can I fix this?

```
class XxxTest {
    @Test
    fun xxx(){
        object : dummyInterface{
            override fun bbb() {
                println("yoyo")
            }

        }
    }

    interface dummyInterface{
        fun bbb()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your function `xxx` uses [Object Expression](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/object-declarations.html#object-expressions) to create an object of anonymous class inheriting from `dummyInterface`. Problem is that you are not using this object anywhere, neither are you storing its reference so it's just created and never called.

For debug to stop at your breakpoint you have to actually call the method.

```
val obj = object : dummyInterface {
    override fun bbb() {
        println("yoyo")
    }
}
obj.bbb()
```